# Does floor topology on R have a countable basis?

Tags: general-topology

Floor topology on R : - Topology generated by basis containing half open intervals [a,b) where a < b are real numbers.
Does it have a countable basis?

Comment: I'd say no. Say, $x<1$ is not an endpoint of such basis intervals. How could you get $[x,1)$ with only unions from the basis?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Suppose $\{[a_i, b_i): i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a countable set of half-open intervals. Let $x$ be some real such that $x\not=a_i$ for any $i$ (such an $x$ exists since the reals are *not* countable); can we ever have $$\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}[a_i, b_i)=[x, \infty)?$$ Do you see how to turn this into a proof that the floor topology has no countable basis?